# Set-DefaultScaffolder : Could not find scaffolder 'Mailer.Razor' in Visual Studio 2017 and MVC Mailer 4.0.5

Tags: visual-studio-2017, mvcmailer

Under Visual Studio 2017 while installing MVCMailer 4.5.0 I encounter the following error:

Set-DefaultScaffolder : Could not find scaffolder 'Mailer.Razor'

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that when the MVC Mailer package is installed it is installed as 'MvcMailer.4.5' in the packages directory however the manifest must list it as 'MvcMailer.4.5.0'.  When searching for the Mailer.Razor.ps1 script it is looking in the MvcMailer.4.5.0\tools directory but it can't find it because that folder does not exist so the scaffolder can not be set correctly.

The workaround is to install the package with the error.  Then go to the packages directory and make a copy of the 'MvcMailer.4.5' folder and rename it to 'MvcMailer.4.5.0' then uninstall and reinstall the package - this time it will install without any errors and the default Mailer scaffolder will be set correcty.

Comment: still relevant after 2 years passed